# RouteData.values["productID"] es Nulo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando con asp.net con webforms y c# e implemente urls amigables para este proyecto, el problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una pagina `ProductList.aspx` en la cual se puede seleccionar un producto para mandarlo a un carrito de compras por medio de un enlace el cual esta de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductByCart", new {productID = Item.ProductID})%>">
<b>Agregar a Carrito<b>
```

Este enlace me envía a otra pagina en donde se hace el proceso de carrito de compras, pero en el `load_page` que es donde recibo la información el `RouteData.Values` me aparece nulo.

Ya revisé la tabla de rutas y esta correcto, esta es la forma en que se recibe en la pagina la información:

```
if (RouteData.Values["productID"] != null)
{
     productId = Convert.ToInt32((RouteData.Values["ProductID"] ?? String.Empty).ToString());
}
```

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida, Gracias.

Comment: En que contexto se encuentra el link? esta dentro de otro componente. Cuando navega al presionar el link se adapta a lo que defines en `MapPageRoute()` ?

Comment: El link esta en una pagina que llama a la segunda y es la definida en el MapPageRoute el cual esta en el Global.asax asi:  routes.MapPageRoute(
             "ProductByCart",
             "AddToCart/{productID}",
             "~/AddToCart.aspx");

Comment: Pero al recibir el parametro con el ID del producto esta nulo el RouteData.Values, no entiendo por que si la llamada es correcta ya que si entra a la pagina AddToCart.

Comment: validaste que no exista la key o que RouteData es null? porque puede que la key sea key sensitive, por lo que debas usar `RouteData.Values["productID"]` con la `p` en minuscula

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda Lendro, si estoy validando la RouteData de esta forma: if (RouteData.Values["productID"] != null) y la key si esta como se definio en minuscula.

Comment: si pones un brakpoint y pasas el mouse por sobre `Values` que valores observas que vienen

Comment: me aparece nulo, hay un count y esta en cero